# How to inject CSS into an iFrame in Node Webkit?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js

I'm working on a small mac app version of a web app using nw.js and want to style it to look  more "mac-app" like: How would I inject custom CSS into the iFrame that loads the app?

I've tried the standard way but it doesn't work because they're from different domains.

E.g. I pull in an iFrame of an external website:

```
<body>
<iframe id="app" src="https://example.com" nwdisable nwfaketop>
</iframe>
</body>
```

and want to put my own custom CSS on top of the iFrame.

Comment: use `postMessage()` from the outside and `addEventListener("message")` from the inside.

Comment: Please add some code to support your question and some more explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<webview>` instead. It comes from chrome and is [documented there](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview).

```
<body>
    <webview id="app" src="https://example.com"></webview>
</body>
<script>
    var wv = document.getElementById("app");
    wv.addEventListener("loadcommit", function(e){
        wv.insertCSS({code: "style {  }"}); // or...
        wv.insertCSS({file: "styles.css"});
    });
</script>
```

(Untested code)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use an `iframe` and not a [`webview`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview), you may be able to disable the cross-origin security with [`chromium-args`](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Manifest%20Format/#chromium-args) such as `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome))

Then you could theoretically inject CSS in the "standard way":

```
var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
iframe.onload = function(){
    var doc = iframe.contentDocument;
    var style = doc.createElement("style");
    style.type = "text/css";
    style.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(css));
    doc.head.appendChild(style);
};
```